# Gather serveral columns at once in r

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to `gather()` a data.frame, but somehow it is not doing what I want.
This is my data:

```
df <- data.frame("id" = c(1),
                 "reco_1"= c(2),
                 "sim_1" = c(2),
                 "title_1"= c(2),
                 "reco_2" = c(3),
                 "sim_2" = c(3),
                 "title_2"= c(3))
```

And this is what it looks like printed:

```
> df
  id reco_1 sim_1 title_1 reco_2 sim_2 title_2
1  1      2     2       2      3     3       3
```

When I now `gather()` my df, it looks like this:

```
> df %>% gather(reco, sim, -id)
  id    reco sim
1  1  reco_1   2
2  1   sim_1   2
3  1 title_1   2
4  1  reco_2   3
5  1   sim_2   3
6  1 title_2   3
```

However, what I would like to have is the following structure:

```
  id  reco  sim  title
1  1  2     2    2
2  2  3     3    3
```

I would appreciate any help, since I do not even know whether `gather()` is even the right verb for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = c(".value", "new_id"), names_sep = "_") %>% 
  select(-id)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  new_id  reco   sim title
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1          2     2     2
2 2          3     3     3
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch! Changed it

Comment: Pivot_longer is the new gather from the tidyr package